# How to Change Permissions: Permission Denied Shiny app on EC2 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny

I am trying to host a shiny app on an AWS EC2 for the first time. I have been following this [tutorial] (https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/guide-shiny-aws/#3-how-to-configure-shiny-server).

I adjusted my `sudo nano /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` with `sanitize_errors false;` so the errors display at http://18.144.34.215:3838/. It seems I do not have the correct permission allocated to that folder from the shiny-server.

This is my first attempt at hosting a shiny app on EC2 and a bit lost from other posts I have found searching. What would be the correct commands to give permission to this folder?

Also, please let me know what info you need from me in order to understand this error better.

Here are my folder permission for 'RIBBiTR_DataRepository'

```
-rw-rwSr-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35149 Feb  1 21:32 LICENSE
-rw-rwSr-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    10 Feb  1 21:32 README.md
drwxrwsrwx 5 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Feb  1 21:38 RIBBiTR_DataRepository
-rw-rwSr-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   205 Feb  1 21:32 db_forms.Rproj
drwxrwsr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Feb  1 21:32 misc
```

And to add, when I try to view the logs I receive a permission denied

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-21:/var/log/shiny-server$ sudo tail RIBBiTR_DataRepository-shiny-20230201-215702-44689.log
su: ignoring --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive with --login
-bash: line 1: cd: /srv/shiny-server/db_forms/RIBBiTR_DataRepository: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in my shiny-server.conf file. I updated the file with a user group, `run_as ubuntu;`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when following the same tutorial. To fix this, instead of symlink my app folder to `/srv/shiny-server`, I just "physically" move it to the folder:

- Remove the symlinked app folder:

```
cd /srv/shiny-server
sudo rm -R my_app
```

- Instead of symlink the app with `ln`, I move the folder instead:

```
sudo mv ~/my_app .
```

Now I can both access the logs and shiny server page without any permission issue.